# Capistrano with multiple Puma applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, puma

I want to deploy multiple rails applications to one Virtual Machine via capistrano.

Both applications in `deploy.rb` have that kind of setting:

```
set :puma_bind, "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
```

They have their own Nginx Config files.

**First App:**

```
upstream puma {
   server unix:///var/www/first-app/shared/tmp/sockets/first-app-puma.sock;
}

server {
   listen 80 default_server deferred;
```

**Second App:**

```
upstream puma_second {
  server unix:///var/www/second-app/shared/tmp/sockets/second-app-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 81;
```

First is on 80 port, second is on 81 port.

However, when I deploy second app then restart Nginx, then I open `example.com:81`, **it shows me pages of first app without any styles.**

Why this is happening? Do I need to bind second app to somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by changing `nginx.conf` files of both applications.

First App:

```
upstream puma_first_app {
   server unix:///var/www/first_app/shared/tmp/sockets/first_app-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 9999;
```

And where `location @puma` I have added this:

```
proxy_pass http://puma_first_app;
```

In second app I used port 80 and changed `first_app` strings to `second app`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried leaving both on port 80 and adding different server_names on each server block for the apps?

```
server { 
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name railsapp1.com;

  . 
  . 
  .
}
```

and

```
server { 
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  server_name railsapp2.com;
  .
  .
}
```